# How get the all codes which is run previously command line SQL in an Oracle 10G Express Edition?

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-xe

How can I get all the codes and commands which was executed previously command line SQL of the Oracle 10G Express Edition to new SQL command line?

Like from tempfiles or something else. My OS is Windows.

Comment: Please do not add voting advice to your questions. In general, good content here is not downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do that:

- open CMD
- connect to the database using SQL Plus
- recall previous commands by pressing the "UP" keyboard key

  - they are recalled line-by-line, not as a whole command, which means that if you'd like to recall something like this:

    ```
    select ename
    from emp
    where deptno = 10
    ```

    you'll need to press the UP key 3 times
  - note that - if you want to run the last command (no matter how many lines it spans) - enter slash `/` at the `SQL>` prompt and hit the ENTER key
- even if you exit SQL Plus, no problem as long as you keep the same CMD window open; just connect again and the same functionality will still be available, in your new SQL Plus session
- however, it'll be lost if you close the CMD window

The bottom line is: GUI tools are much more appropriate in this context.

Comment: i lose my data by mistake i close my CMD is there any solution to get that data in new CMD??

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no such option in SQL*Plus.